# Executing commands stored in ADX table

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a metadata table and one of the columns stores Kusto commands. Is there a way to execute these?

I tried creating an ADF pipeline with two ADX Command activities in sequence:

1. The first activity is supposed to fetch the commands from the table using the "`MyTable | project command_column`".
2. The result of this is sent to the second ADX Command activity to run.

The issue is that "`MyTable | project command_column`" is not a command, it's a query so I can't even use ADX Command activity for this.

The table does store commands indeed , but to get that command data out of the table we obviously need to be able to query it.

What's the simplest solution for something like this?

This is not some automation thing, it's a one time job. But the table has more than a few hundred rows so doing it manually is not a solution either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is not some automation thing, it's a one time job. But the table has more than a few hundred rows so doing it manually is not a solution either.

An alternative way would be:

1. Exporting the output of the first query to a file/script (a table, where each row includes a single string value that represents a control command)
2. Using [Kusto.Cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/tools/kusto-cli) to invoke the commands in the file/script from #1

*Note:* you'll need to add any necessary error handling, as Kusto.Cli will only run the commands for you and report their outcome

- some commands may succeed, some may fail - depending on the content of your commands and the state of the entities the commands run against

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use Flow for that, see more information here: https://radennis.github.io/Ravit-Blog/blogs/KustoAndFlow.html

Specifically, you can have one flow, the first action would be "run query and list results" to get the list of commands.

The second one would be "run command and visualize results", which would get as input the previous command and execute it.